# Missing HTML form element

Tags: php, html

The specific problem is that the textbox is not showing on my page. I am actually following a tutorial on building a simple forum. Can you assist me in identifying this error?

```
<?php
echo '<tr> <td colspan = "2"> <h2> Reply: </h2> <br/>
    <form method = "post" action = "reply.php? id = '. $row ['Topicid'].
  '<textarea name= "reply-content"> </textarea>'. '<br/>'. '<br/>'.
        '<input type= "submit" value = "Post Reply"/>
    </Form> </td> </tr>';
?>
```

Comment: what is the html  page source

Comment: use small letter for form closing </form>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues in your code.
First of all, you aren't closing the first form tag and second, you are closing the `<form>` tag with a `</Form>` tag.
Your code should be like thhis:

```
<?php
echo '<tr> <td colspan = "2"> <h2> Reply: </h2> <br/>
    <form method = "post" action = "reply.php? id = '. $row ['Topicid'].
  '"><textarea name= "reply-content"> </textarea>'. '<br/>'. '<br/>'.
        '<input type= "submit" value = "Post Reply"/>
    </form> </td> </tr>';
?>
```